# Is there a way to throw a warning when wrong return type is used for controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger

I am building a Web Api with with `Asp.Net Core 2.2`. I am using `swagger` to test my endpoints. My models are constantly evolving and when I refactor some method to return different type than before it is really easy to miss changing this type in controller as part of `ActionResult<T>`.

A simplified example:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        int myNumber = 1;
        return Ok(myNumber);
    }
```

This will work fine, except that it will show wrong return type in `swagger` (It will show return type if `string` even though it actually returns `int`). Is there a way to produce a warning for this situation?

EDIT 1: Providing more detailed example:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyOtherClass
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    }

    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<MyClass> Get()
    {
        var myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();
        return Ok(myOtherClass);
    }
```

If I run following in `swagger` I will get:

[image]

I not expecting it to throw an error, but a warning would be nice.

P.S. the idea that there could be a warning came from a package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers` which generates a warning in a following situation:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<MyClass> Get()
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

When building i get the following: `warning API1000: Action method returns undeclared status code '400'.`

Answer (score 0):

Swagger reports the return as a `string` because that's what you're telling it to do. The `int` is actually being coerced to a `string`. You basically just got lucky (unlucky?) here that that's doable by the framework. If you were returning something that couldn't be automatically coerced to the return type, then it would throw an exception.

As such, there's not really a warning to be had here. If anything, I'd just avoid returning strings for the most part, or at least start developing your methods with a more rigid type such as bool. For example you can just stub it out like:

```
public ActionResult<bool> MyAwesomeAction()
{
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Then, build your method out, and when you're ready to do a real return, change `true` to what you're actually returning. That will then cause a syntax error, because your return type cannot be interpreted as `bool`, prompting you to change the generic param as well.

Comment: But it doesn't throw even if type cannot be casted. Please see my updated example with the response.